# How to build a SDK with Yocto including CMake?

Tags: sdk, cmake, yocto

I want to distribute a cross compiling toolchain(SDK) for my embedded system. I created an own layer in which all libs etc. are included. By entering:

```
bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk
```

I can generate a toolchain, where all headers and libs are included.
Now I want to include not only a lib but cmake.

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following line to your image:

```
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += "nativesdk-cmake"
```

That will add `cmake` to your SDK.